# Output of 1 query to be used a input of another to get results

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have an index1 which gives me a list of unique ID's [1,2,3,4,5]

```
| stats count by uniqueId
```

Not sure how to store the above result to get it used for another query.

Index2
I want to use the result [1,2,3,4] for the next query which will give me some extra information based on the ID only.
E.g.: Query 2 has
`index=xyz id=1, val=abc`

How can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is about subsearches (but it's hard to tell from your description)

Do you mean something like this?

```
index=ndx1 sourcetype=srctp1 val=abc 
    [| search index=ndx2 sourcetype=src2 id=*
    | stats count by id
    | fields - count ]
| stats count by val id
```

Splunk will use the list of `id` returned from the subsearch to filter the outer search